# setting hours for individual days in the schedule

Tags: angular

I have a plan to make such a schedule in angular and I want to use the interface to be able to set ranges of hours, e.g. with breaks for individual days of the week, either by clicking on these squares, or even better by dragging (like cells in Excel). Can anyone help me to get down to it? Any advice?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

firstly you should design this layout ,i think you can use bootstap layout(container-row-column) and create buttons for each hour in per day at row, Then you can assign events to the buttons as you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I did, but it looks terrible https://codepen.io/olivier-mazur/pen/VwMaKjj

Comment: you should add css class for column  like weekdays , hour